# Redux Action "Type alias 'Action' circularly references itself"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have two actions:

```
export const addToCart = (id: string, qty: number) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  getState: () => RootState
) => {
  const { data }: { data: IProduct } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);
  dispatch({
    type: CartActionTypes.CARD_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      qty,
    },
  });

  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};

export const removeItem = (item: CartProduct) => ({
  type: CartActionTypes.CARD_REMOVE_ITEM,
  payload: item,
});
```

I create Action union type and pass it to the reducer but it gives me "Type alias 'Action' circularly references itself" and I have no clue what it means.

```
export type Action =
  | ReturnType<typeof addToCart>
  | ReturnType<typeof removeItem>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with circular references happens when you have two generic types, that refer to one another:

```js
type Bar<T> = T;
type Foo = Bar<Foo>;
```

As you can see, this expands to: `type Foo = Bar<Foo> = Foo = Bar<Foo> = ...`, ie. you get a circular reference.

In your case, the offending function is the first action creator:

```js
export const addToCart = (id: string, qty: number) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  getState: () => RootState
) => {
```

By passing `getState: () => RootState`, you introduce a circular reference, since `RootState` is a union that includes `export type Action` you export later on.

To fix this, you must differentiate between **action creators** and **thunks**. Only the former make up the `RootState` (for more reading on the differences I refer you here: https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-thunk/).

So, to sum up, remove `| ReturnType<typeof addToCart>` from `Action` union type, and extract

```js
dispatch({
  type: CartActionTypes.CARD_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
    id: data.id,
    name: data.name,
    image: data.image,
    price: data.price,
    countInStock: data.countInStock,
    qty,
  },
});
```

To an action creator.